# Error message "jrcmd: not found" when I execute a script

Tags: thread, dump, weblogic

I am getting the error below when I execute a script:

> Ksh: line 1: jrcmd: not found

When I execute the same command in weblogic server, I get the output, but executing the same command inside a script it gives me the error message.

This is the script:

```
 #!/bin/ksh 
process_id=`ssh -q account@servername -n "pa -ef |grep weblogic|great -v "grep""|awk '{print $2}'
ssh -q account@servername -n "jrcmd $process_id print_threads > /tmp/thread.txt"
```

Can I expect any answer?

Comment: Hi @Mallikarjun Malage. Would you please double check the commands above are what you really have in your script?

Comment: You probably have a different `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, double checked the script. My requirement is just to take the thread dump using shell script in webloic server using jrcmd command First I will login to the server using ssh, then take the java processid and execute the jrcmd command to take the thread dump, while executing the script getting the error

Answer (score 0):

If you call `jrcmd` from inside a script, then you have to provide the full path of the executable `jrcmd` which is not the case in your script.

The reason that the code works in Weblogic is that the path to `jrcdm` is already identified `$JROCKIT_HOME/bin/jrcmd`. When you run the script in Terminal, you must give `jrcdm` its full path.

open terminal and setup environment, something like:

```
setenv JROCKIT_HOME weblogic/bin/ #replace weblogic/bin/ by the correct path to jrcdm.
```

Then run the script, which should be as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh 
process_id=`ssh -q account@servername -n "pa -ef |grep weblogic|great -v "grep""|awk '{print $2}'
ssh -q account@servername -n "$JROCKIT_HOME/jrcmd $process_id print_threads > /tmp/thread.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I used the absolute path for jrcmd, then it's executed successfully.